# Memoization involving binomial coefficients

Tags: scheme, memoization

I have a question on how to do a memoization for functions that require two inputs. I have the code for how to do a memoization for something like finding the nth fibonacci number, which I will post here:

```
(define (fib3 n)
  (local 
    {(define hash identity)
     (define v (make-vector (add1 n) empty))
     (define (get n l) ; num (listof pair) -> false or the pair with n
       (cond
         [(empty? l) false]
         [(= (pair-a (first l)) n) (first l)]
         [else (get n (rest l))]))
     (define (put n r) ; num result -> result
       (begin (vector-set! v (hash n) (cons (make-pair n r) (vector-ref v (hash n))))
              r))
     (define (fib-helper n)
       (match (get n (vector-ref v (hash n)))
         [(struct pair (_ b)) b]
         [false (put n (cond
                         [(= n 0) 1]
                         [(= n 1) 1]
                         [else (+ (fib-helper (- n 1)) (fib-helper (- n 2)))]))]))}
    (fib-helper n)))
```

However, I am a bit confused on how to implement it for a binomial coefficient function. My normal recursive case looks like this:

`(define (comb-recursive m l)
  (cond 
    [(< m l) 0]
    [(or (= l 0) (= m l)) 1]
    [else (+ (comb-recursive (sub1 m) (sub1 l)) 
             (comb-recursive (sub1 m) l))]))`

I do not really know how to change this such that it does memoization. Are there any tips that would help me tackle this question and use a format similar to the fib function described above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Your fibonacci example is overly complicated.

The base procedure is:

```
(define fib
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
      ((= n 0) 1)
      ((= n 1) 1)
      (else  (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))))
```

To do memoïzation in this function, convert it to something like this:

```
(define fib
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (lambda (n)
      (or
       (hash-ref cache n #f)
       (let ((res (cond
                    ((= n 0) 1)
                    ((= n 1) 1)
                    (else  (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))))
         (hash-set! cache n res)
         res)))))
```

Now if you have more than one parameter, your hash key will simply be the **list of your parameters**, e.g. for `(comb-recursive m l)` the key to the hash will be the list `(m l)`. The easiest way to get this is do define your procedure as `(lambda args ...)` - note that there are no parentheses around the parameter `args`; this means that the actual parameters (one or more) will get bound to a list called `args` in this case. The real parameters will be destructured later with a `match` statement, when needed:

```
(define comb-recursive
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (lambda args ; all arguments are in a list here
      (or
       (hash-ref cache args #f)
       (let ((res (match args
                    ((list m l) ; destructure arguments
                     (cond 
                       [(< m l) 0]
                       [(or (= l 0) (= m l)) 1]
                       [else (+ (comb-recursive (sub1 m) (sub1 l)) 
                                (comb-recursive (sub1 m) l))])))))
         (hash-set! cache args res)
         res)))))
```

**2.** Instead of adapting each procedure as needed, you can also use a more general memoïzation procedure that works for any number of parameters. Since it will not know the real number of parameters, instead of using `match` it will just `apply` the parameter list:

```
(define (memoize fn)
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (lambda arg 
      (hash-ref! cache arg (thunk (apply fn arg))))))
```

It can be used as a generic wrapper around another procedure which doesn't have to be *memoïzation-aware*.

Example for a `fibonacci` procedure:

```
(define fib
  (memoize
   (lambda (n)
     (cond
       ((= n 0) 1) ; based on your example - usually this should be 0?
       ((= n 1) 1)
       (else  (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))))
```

Applied to your procedure `comb-recursive`:

```
(define comb-recursive
  (memoize
   (lambda (m l)
     (cond 
       [(< m l) 0]
       [(or (= l 0) (= m l)) 1]
       [else (+ (comb-recursive (sub1 m) (sub1 l)) 
                (comb-recursive (sub1 m) l))]))))
```

Comment: For the general memoize case, what would fn and arg be for comb? the arg should be (m l)? I have no clue what fn should be equal to. I don't understand what you're trying to say when you're trying to explain the general memoization procedure in racket.

Comment: I added an non-general example for your procedure, that should make it clearer (I hope).

Comment: @WillNess Thank you ;-) It is Racket-specific now but can easily be ported to standard Scheme; `(thunk` is `(lambda ()`, `match` can be replaced by `apply`, and you'd need to change the hash-procedures. But the approach is entirely applicable to any Scheme implementation.